# used padding on products, so i can't center now

Tags: html, css, product

I have a few products, and i used padding/margin to give a space between them.
Of course the last one has a padding too so it does not center good.
I will give you the link [Website](http://starlinedesign.nl/spaaz_final/producten.html), but not the code because I want to know how you can center products in general even when you use padding on them.
There should be a "special way"

EDIT:

This is what I mean, 1 is what I get and 2 is what I want. (the dark ones are the products, the light box on the right side is the padding/margin and the biggest one is the wrapper)
[image]

Comment: usually a simple wrapper should be enough, just position the wrapping element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `first-child()` to select the first `div` and dont give it a padding.
Or you can use an `id` to the first `div` and give `padding:0;`

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this should help you

```
.wrapper {
  padding:30px;
  text-align:center;
}
.products {
  margin:15px;
  padding:15px;
}
```

if it persists i would indicate that you read this article

http://maujor.com/tutorial/centralizando-com-css-um-guia-completo.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to have css calculate padding in the width of the element.

Default box-sizing behaviour is as follow: Total Width = Width Element + Padding width. With this the padding is added "outside" of the box model.

When you set the box-sizing to border box, the padding of an element will get calculated to be "inside" the box.

Here is an article explaining this behaviour: [Link to Article](http://callmenick.com/2014/03/26/box-sizing-reset-border-box/)